# What should an HTML 5 form submit when no value is set

Tags: php, html, forms

I was wondering what an HTML form should submit when no value is set for the input.

I have a PHP project with smarty which has some forms.
One of the forms has an input like this:

```
<form name="frm_login" method="POST">  
...            
    <div class="login-button">                            
        <input class="button-short" type="submit" name="send_login" onclick="return storeSelector.checkStoreId()">
    </div>
</form>
```

Chrome and Cliqz see this:

```
<input class="button-short" type="submit" name="send_login" onclick="return storeSelector.checkStoreId()">
```

The IE 11 sees this

```
<input name="send_login" class="button-short" onclick="return storeSelector.checkStoreId()" type="submit" value="Anfrage senden">
```

And my "own" Browser (CefSharp version 1.25) sees this: //I know its not supported anymore ... but you know .Net 2.0

```
<input class="button-short" type="submit" name="send_login" onclick="return storeSelector.checkStoreId()">
```

So when I hit the submit button

- Chrome sends in the `$_Post["send_login"]  "Submit"`
- IE11 sends in the `$_Post["send_login"] "Anfrage Senden"` <-- German for send request
- My Browser sends in the `$_Post["send_login"] ""`
- Cliqz sends in the `$_Post["send_login"] "Daten Absenden"` <-- German for send data

I was wondering:

1. what is the correct behaviour if no value is set ?
2. Should the browser send something it likes or is it correct to send nothing ?
3. Is there something written in a RFC ?

Comment: Question is: Is the value not set, or is it just not set *from your html*. I think a browser can set a default value (like "Anvrage Senden") for the submit button, and that is also the value that is shown and posted, unless you explicitly specify the value attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### HTML 5.1 Specification

**What is the correct behavior if no value is set ?**

If the value is not set it should be an empty string.

> The value content attribute gives the default value of the input
> element. When the value content attribute is added, set, or removed,
> if the control's dirty value flag is false, the user agent must set
> the value of the element to the value of the value content attribute,
> if there is one, or the empty string otherwise, and then run the
> current value sanitization algorithm, if one is defined.

https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/the-input-element.html#attr-input-value

**Should the browser send something it likes or is it correct to send nothing ?**

According to [how form data is constructed](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/sec-forms.html#constructing-the-form-data-set) before sent, every submittable elements is initialized regardless of settings or value. This should differ from 4.01 that even disabled elements are sent with an empty value.

> 2. Let the form data set be a list of name-value-type tuples, initially
>    empty.

And they are never unset.

**Is there something written in a RFC ?**

Nope, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866#section-8.2.
Some rules on checkboxes and radiobuttons are.

### HTML 4.01 Specification

**What is the correct behavior if no value is set ?**

If the value is not set it should be `undefined`.

The control's "current value" is first set to the initial value. Thereafter, the control's current value may be modified through user interaction and scripts.

> A control's initial value does not change. Thus, when a form is reset,
> each control's current value is reset to its initial value. If a
> control does not have an initial value, the effect of a form reset on
> that control is undefined.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#current-value

**Should the browser send something it likes or is it correct to send nothing ?**

Simply said, no.

The form data set is based on values of [successful controls](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls)

> If a control doesn't have a current value when the form is submitted,
> user agents are not required to treat it as a successful control.

So there is no standard behaviour.

**Is there something written in a RFC ?**

Nope, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866#section-8.2.
Some rules on checkboxes and radiobuttons are.